# Rpy2 and --max-ppsize

Tags: python, r, rpy2

I'm running some recursive code in R through Rpy2 (has to be that way, unfortunately). I've had to increase options(expressions) but haven't found a way to increase the pointer protection stack. I've looked through the rpy2 code, and can't find an obvious place to set the flag for this. Is it even possible?

The errors I'm getting are:

```
protect(): protection stack overflow.
```

I have looked at https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-help/2006-August/111127.html

Thanks for helping!

Comment: try: https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-help/2006-August/111127.html - and read through the threads - that was the first search engine result I got using "rpy2 protection stack overflow"

Comment: Thanks. I've been through that thread. Not really an analog to the problem I'm having, unfortunately.

Comment: Strong suggest you add research links to your question then...

Comment: Guess I assumed relevant google searching was an obvious precursor to hacking on the rpy2 source code...

Answer (score 1):

Found it buried in the rst files in the source code, but has to be done as initial import

```
import rpy2.rinterface as rinterface 
rinterface.set_initoptions((...))
```

Comment: The .rst files correspond to the documention, for which HTML builds are on the web (and are indexed by search engines):http://rpy.sourceforge.net/rpy2/doc-2.2/html/rinterface.html#initialization

Comment: Thanks, Laurent.  You're totally right.  I just didn't have them compiled locally.